# Your thoughts on Community Ads

Tags: discussion

Once a Stack Exchange site graduates from beta, it shows adverts that are chosen by its community. If any of us are active on a graduated site then there is the opportunity for posting a proposed advert in the appropriate meta question on that site, and if well received by that community it will show on their main site, advertising the existence of Computer Graphics Stack Exchange.

Do any of you have any graduated sites in mind that would be likely to welcome an advert for Computer Graphics?

In this post I'm just looking for your thoughts on community ads and which sites would be potential targets. The specific design of the ads can wait for a separate meta question when we know which sites are being used, so the ads can be tailored to each community.

Please also feel free to raise any concerns or things to keep in mind.

Answer (score 8):

The [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site seems a natural fit. In fact, they [currently carry](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/community-promotion-ads-2016) an ad for 3d Graphics proposal, which is still in Area 51. Their two other active community ads are Worldbuilding and the generic Twitter ad, so there isn't much competition.

Answer (score 4):

[Blender SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) might be an option, but seeing [the recent discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30359730#30359730) it would be important that the ad is completely clear that this site is about graphics *programming* (and research) as opposed to using graphics related software.